# Поехали стили в Swiper

Tags: css

Немного изменил стили свайпера, добавил стрелки и изменил внешний вид пагинации.
Но на разрешении ниже 992px стрелки и пагинация едут вниз, учитывая, что у них position: absolute;, данное поведение весьма странное. Как не ковырял, не могу их "прибить" куда надо.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы не возникало такой проблемы, прописывайте стиль:

```
.swiper-container {height: auto;}
```